# Best way to make table cell wider

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to make the last field (Notes) wider.  Currently the field says "We the people of the United States" as a place holder.  I don't want each row to grow more vertically when the note field has more text in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/sdbEc/

```
<tr>
<td><a href="http://acme.com/pkg_testme.edit_item?p_item_id=1126" align="Right">RS-11</a>           </td>
<td width="300">a description</td>
<td width="200">INSTRUMENT CO</td>
<td width="40">28</td>
<td width="40">2.85</td>
<td width="40">15-OCT-12</td>
<td width="40">Euro</td>
<td width="200">spring scissor</td>
<td width="40">9</td>
<td width="40">2</td>
<td width="40">9</td>
<td width="40">1</td>
<td width="40">2</td>
<td width="40">1</td>
<td width="40">5</td>
<td width="40">9</td>
<td><a href="http://acme.com/pkg_testme2.edit_item?p_item_id=" align="Right"></a></td>
<td><a href="http://acme.com/pkg_testme.edit_notes?  p_item_id=We%20the%20people%20of%20the%20United%20States">We the people of the United  States</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This seemed to be the key    <TD><div style="overflow: auto; height: 60px; width: 200px;">We the people of the United States</div></TD>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I used

```
<TD><div style="overflow: auto; height: 60px; width: 200px;">We the people of the United</div></TD>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use the `width=` attribute on HTML elements. CSS should be used for design.

Second, let the browser decide how to space out the table given the total width constraints. They usually do a pretty good job.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the css :nth-child() selector to better style your tables:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

HTML CODE:

```
<tr class="tableformat">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.tableformat td:nth-child(1){
    width: 300px;
}
.tableformat td:nth-child(2){
    width: 200px;
}
.tableformat td:nth-child(3){
    color: red;
}
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Set the styles with ie. `<td style="width: 40px;">..</td>`

And if you want absolute control.. add `<table style="table-layout:fixed">...</table>`. That will stop the browser entirely from messing with your widths.

Ofcourse styles should be in seperate css files and what not, but learn that somewhere else )

Answer (score 0):

you can try do add a colspan="2" to your TD to make it wider.

Example :

```
<td colspan="2" ></td>
```